# Solarpower and Windpower reusage of code

Tags: python, function

I have programmed a solarpower and a windpower in python with very similar functions. Im thinking if it's good programming style to write two almost identical functions, or should I just try to write one out of the two.

An example is

```
def output_solarpower(lat_energy):
print("Latitude, Year-Average")
a=lat_energy
sort_energy=sort(a)
for element in sort_energy:
    print(' , '.join(map(str,element)))



def output_windpower(dia_energy):
print("Diameter, Year-Average")
a=dia_energy
sort_energy=sort(a)
for element in sort_energy:
    print(' , '.join(map(str,element)))
```

where lat_energy and dia_energy is two different lists that get sorted in the same function?

Comment: The whole point of functions is to not repeat yourself. Just pass different lists to it when it's invoked.

Comment: It seems like those two functions do exactly the same thing, except they print a different message.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is input a second parameter in your function, so you can combine it into one.

```
def output_power(e_type, energy):
  print(e_type + " Year-Average")
  a=energy
  sort_energy=sort(a)
  for element in sort_energy:
    print(' , '.join(map(str,element)))
```

If you want the `dia_energy` you can run `output_power("Diameter", dia_energy)`. To make it latitude , run `output_power("Latitude", lat_energy)`.